# How to use Java to encode/decode/transcode byte array using a charset directly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, character-encoding, malformed

I have a malformed string which may be caused by a *bug* of MySQL JDBC driver,

The bytes of a sample malformed string (`malformed_string.getBytes("UTF-8")`) is this:

```
C3 A4 C2 B8 C2 AD C3 A6 E2 80 93 E2 80 A1  (UTF-8 twice)
```

which should encoded the following bytes (it's already UTF-8 encoded, but treat them as ISO-8859-1 enoded)

```
----- ----- ----- ----- -------- --------
  E4   B8    AD     E6     96       87     (UTF-8)
```

which should encoded the following Unicode BigEndian bytes

```
---------------     ---------------------
     4E 2D                65 87            (Unicode BigEndian)
```

I want to decode the 1st one to the 2nd one, I tried `new String(malformed_string.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1")`, but it does not transcode as expected. I'm wondering if there's something like `byte[] encode/decode (byte[] src, String charsetName)`, or how to achieve the transcode above in java?

**Background:**

I have a MySQL table which have Chinese column names, when I update such columns with long data, MySQL JDBC driver thrown an exception like this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ä¸­æ–‡' at row 1
```

The column name in the exception is malformed, it should be "中文", and it must be correctly displayed to user as the following.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column '中文' at row 1
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's MySQL statement to demonstrate how the malformed string occured, and how to restore it to correct string

```
show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                    |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                     |
| character_set_connection | utf8                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                   |
| character_set_results    | utf8                     |
| character_set_server     | utf8                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                     |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+

-- encode
select
    hex(convert(convert(unhex('E4B8ADE69687') using UTF8) using ucs2)) as `hex(src in UNICODE)`,
    unhex('E4B8ADE69687') `src in UTF8`,
    'E4B8ADE69687' `hex(src in UTF8)`,
    hex(convert(convert(unhex('E4B8ADE69687') using latin1) using UTF8)) as `hex(src in UTF8->Latin1->UTF8)`;
+---------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| hex(src in UNICODE) | src in UTF8 | hex(src in UTF8) | hex(src in UTF8->Latin1->UTF8) |
+---------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| 4E2D6587            | 中文        | E4B8ADE69687     | C3A4C2B8C2ADC3A6E28093E280A1   |
+---------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


-- decode
select
    unhex('C3A4C2B8C2ADC3A6E28093E280A1') as `malformed`,
    'C3A4C2B8C2ADC3A6E28093E280A1' as `hex(malformed)`,
    hex(convert(convert(unhex('C3A4C2B8C2ADC3A6E28093E280A1') using utf8) using latin1)) as `hex(malformed->UTF8->Latin1)`,
    convert(convert(convert(convert(unhex('C3A4C2B8C2ADC3A6E28093E280A1') using utf8) using latin1) using binary)using utf8) `malformed->UTF8->Latin1->binary->UTF8`;
+----------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| malformed      | hex(malformed)               | hex(malformed->UTF8->Latin1) | malformed->UTF8->Latin1->binary->UTF8 |
+----------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ä¸­æ–‡         | C3A4C2B8C2ADC3A6E28093E280A1 | E4B8ADE69687                 | 中文                                  |
+----------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

The punch line is the way to transcode using only the jdk classes is :

```
try {
byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] defaultBytes = original.getBytes();

String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "ISO-885-9");
System.out.println("roundTrip = " + roundTrip);
System.out.println();
printBytes(utf8Bytes, "utf8Bytes");
System.out.println();
printBytes(defaultBytes, "defaultBytes");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For a more robust transcoding mechanism I suggest you check out ICU>

Comment: i test a lot, i found i misunderstand `new String(bytes, charsetName)` and `getBytes(charsetName)`, `new String` is decoding, and `getBytes` is encoding. so `new String(malformed_string.getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-8")` is the solution, and `ISO-8859-1` must be replaced by `Windows-1252`, because there's no characters between 0x80-0x9F in ISO-8859-1 charset. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout